# Why can't I resize partitions?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, resize

I am trying to install Windows 7 (Ubuntu installed first).

I try to resize my partition but everything is greyed out but unmount, info and manage flags.

I am also using the partition I am trying to resize.

And im not trying to dual boot

Comment: if you are not trying to dual boot, what is the purpose of the resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Mounted partitions cannot be re-sized. Umouont the partition and you will be able to re-size it.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize mounted partitions. To resize your Ubuntu partition (or any mounted partition for that matter) you will need to boot into a liveCD/liveUSB. From the live environment you should be able to resize your partition to your hearts content. hope this helps!